# How to use the update method for a generic LINQ to SQL repository

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have implemented the following generic methods:

```
public IQueryable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
    return context.GetTable<T>().Where(filter);
}

public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
    context.GetTable<T>().Attach(entity);        
}
```

I am not sure how to implement this in a consumer class? Ideally, I would like to pass in a userref and update the user accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
public IQueryable<T> Query<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
    return context.GetTable<T>().Where(filter);
}

public virtual void Update<T>(T entity)
{
    context.GetTable<T>().Attach(entity);        
}

var user=something.Query<User>(x=>x.Name=="bla bla").First;
user.Name="alb alb";
something.Update(user);
```

But consider avoiding writing generic repositories. You don't gain that much from them. If it's generic, exposes IQueryable, takes in Expression filters, it's quite useless abstraction layer and just adds complexity.